# SET IDENTITY_INSERT not working when using TransactionScope in Entity Framework Core 3

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having issues using `TransactionScope` in EF Core 3. The code below works fine when using `Database.BeginTransaction` but not when using `TransactionScope`. 
The code below doesn't work:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(option, new TransactionOptions
            {
                Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout,
                IsolationLevel = isolation
            }, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT ITEMS ON");
    Context.Item.Add(item);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get the following error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Items' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

This code does work:

```
using(var ts = Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT ITEMS ON");
    Context.Item.Add(item);
    Context.SaveChanges();
    ts.Commit();
}
```

How can I make it work with a `TransactionScope`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open and close the connection yourself, otherwise EF will open/close for each operations. Your `ExecuteRawSql` and your `SaveChanges` are effectively done on different connections.

```
Context.Item.Add(item);
Context.Database.OpenConnection();
try
{
    Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT ITEMS ON");
    Context.SaveChanges();
    Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT ITEMS OFF");
}
finally
{
    Context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties#explicit-values-into-sql-server-identity-columns